# EF inheritance with table splitting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to map two different EF models to the same table SharedTable, let us call them EntityA and EntityB. I made them both extend a base Entity called BaseEntity.

EntityA is defined only with SharedTable fields, EntityB has fields in SharedTable and EntityBTable.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
            .Map<EntityA>(m => m.Requires("IsEntityA").HasValue<bool>(true))
            .Map<EntityB>(m => m.Requires("IsEntityA").HasValue<false>(true));

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityBMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityAMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BaseEntityMap());
```

The models look like this

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SharedTableField1 { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA : BaseEntity
{
    public int SharedTableField2 { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : BaseEntity
{
    public int EntityBTableField1 { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings are

```
public class BaseEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity>
{
    public BaseEntityMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.ToTable("SharedTable");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.SharedTableField1).HasColumnName("SharedTableField1");
    }
}

public class EntityAMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityA>
{
    public EntityAMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.ToTable("SharedTable");
        this.Property(t => t.SharedTableField2).HasColumnName("SharedTableField2");
    }
}

public class EntityBMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityB>
{
    public EntityBMap()
    {
        Map(c =>
        {
            HasKey(t => t.Id);
            Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            c.Properties(t => new
            {
                t.SharedTableField2
            });
            c.ToTable("SharedTable");
        });

        Map(c =>
        {
            c.Properties(t => new
            {
                t.EntityBTableField1
            });
            c.ToTable("EntityBTable");
        });
    }
}
```

The error I get says:

A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The type 'EntityB' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting.

Any way around this?

Comment: Why do you want to map `t.EntityBTableField1` to another table? (Which is referred to as *entity splitting*).

Comment: It makes sense to store it in another table as it will not be used in all the records, hence reducing the amount of data retrieved when it does not need to be fetched.

Comment: That may make sense if it's about large objects or expensive calculated fields in reality. I wouldn't worry about a couple of `int`s or other small types. And you can also use projections (`Select(x => new { ... }`) to confine the amount of fields in the query result.

Comment: Thanks Gert, this is a simplified scenario I created for asking the question, but the real data that needs to be moved is pretty massive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance strategy you've chosen is [Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt).

You've got three types: one base type `BaseEntity` and two derived types `EntityA` and `EntityB`. You decided to put them into three separate tables. The `BaseEntity` properties of both `EntityA` and `EntityB` will be put in one table. `EntityA` and `EntityB` each have a foreign key to their base properties in the `BaseEntity` table.

Whether this inheritance strategy is the best for your problem depends on whether you will mostly query for "BaseEntities that ..." or for "EntityA that ..." and "EntityTyB that ..."

Could it be that using [Table per concrete class (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) would be more suitable for your problem?

If you choose TPT inheritance strategy, then for every query "EntityA with some base class properties that ..." will need a join.

If you'd use TPC this join would not be needed. However TPC has the disadvantage that a Concat between the two tables is required whenever you ask for "BaseEntities that ...".

So it depends what kind of queries you will do most often which inheritance strategy is the best for your needs.

If you want to stick to strategy TPT, it seems that you don't build your model correctly.

- You don't want anyone to store `BaseEntity` objects on its own. If you'd allow that, it wouldn't be inheritance, but one-to-zero-or-one relation: every `EntityA` belongs to one `BaseEntity`, and every `BaseEntity` has zero or one 'EntityA`. This is not what you want: every`BaseEntity`has exactly either one`EntityA`or one '`EntityB`, and every 'EntityA` / `EntityB` has exactly one 'BaseEntity`
- As you don't want to store`BaseEntity` objects without the derived class, 'BaseEntity` class ought to be declared abstract, as in the given link for TPT.
- In the class definitions of `EntityA` en `EntityB`, don't mention the foreign key to the `BaseEntity` table. Again, see the given link to the TPT

> I think the abstract base class and the lack of foreign keys are the
>   key information to let entity framework know that you chose
>   inheritance strategy TPT.

- In your model building, only mention the table names and if needed the column names. Don't mention the foreign keys

When I built your model like this, entity framework created the three tables like TPT. any extra fluent API nor attributes were needed. Even though I didn't mention the foreign keys, Entity Framework knew they were needed as a polymorphic association. Again see the link to TPT

By the way, is the [Required] on your integers useful? Even if I wanted to, I couldn't give this integers a null value. Didn't you mean [Key]? As you are following the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) even that is not necessary.